# Print with escape characters in go templates

Tags: go, go-templates

Assuming I have a parameter whose value is a string with a series of escape characters:

```
strct.Data = "{ \"hello\": \"ok\", \r\n \"text\": \"value\" }"
```

When I print this in templates, assuming the template markup is:

```
value = `{{ .Data }}`
```

The rendered output becomes:

```
value = `{ "hello": "ok",
"text": "value"
}`
```

Is there any built-in feature which allows for printing the RAW text (exactly as it is)? so that the following output would be achieved:

```
value = `{ "hello": "ok", \r\n "text": "value" }`
```

Comment: @CeriseLimón: Please check it out here https://go.dev/play/p/L8XkJOJcmUw